# Covariance vs Pearson Correlation Coefficient

Tags: probability

Assume that is given a Gaussian Distribution with positive definite covariance matrix $\Sigma$. For some off diagonal elements we have $|\Sigma_{i,j}|>|\Sigma_{i,k}|>|\Sigma_{i,l}|>...$ . Is it true that $|\rho_{i,j}|>|\rho_{i,k}|>|\rho_{i,l}|>...$ ?  ($\rho$ is the correlation coefficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, a quick note on definitions: I think you probably intended to write "Covariance vs. Pearson Correlation Coefficient" in the title; the quantities $\Sigma_{i,j}$ are called covariances.

There is a simple relationship between the covariance of two random variables and the Pearson correlation coefficient:

$\rho_{i,j} = \Sigma_{i, j}/(\sigma_i \sigma_j)$

where $\sigma_i, \sigma_j$ are the standard deviations of the concerned random variables.

Therefore, $\Sigma_{i,j} > \Sigma_{i,k} > \Sigma_{i,l}$ is exactly equivalent to $\rho_{i, j} \sigma_i \sigma_j > \rho_{i, k} \sigma_i \sigma_k > \rho_{i, l} \sigma_i \sigma_l $. Cancelling the common factor of $\sigma_i$ in each term, we obtain

$\rho_{i, j} \sigma_j > \rho_{i, k} \sigma_k> \rho_{i, l} \sigma_l$

which is not equivalent to the relationship between the correlation coefficients in your question. Intuitively, if one of the random variables has a large standard deviation/variance, this can lead to a large covariance even if the correlation coefficient is close to 0.